# Apache subversion work with browser only

Tags: svn, apache2

I tried to set up a svn repository follow this guide: https://tecadmin.net/install-subversion-server-on-ubuntu/

The problem is I can use browser to access repo but It's not working with Tortoise or command line. I got an error:

svn: E195019: Redirect cycle detected for URL 'http://myserver/svn/myrepo'

My dav_svn.conf:

```
Alias /svn /var/lib/svn
<Location /svn>

   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/lib/svn

   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion Repository"
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
   Require valid-user

</Location>
```

I searched and got many answers as: change Document Root,.. . But they didn't helpful.

I installed repo on Ubuntu 16.04

Thanks a lot for your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the first line `Alias /svn /var/lib/svn` should not be there and is causing this error.

Comment: But if that is not there, how does Apache resolve the /svn URI?